# Jenkins folder is not created, but Jenkins works fine

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm very new to Docker and Jenkins, but following the documentation, it was very easy to run the installation and to have it up and running.
However, I'm very confused about where the Jenkins volume or directory is.

I'm on Windows10.

By doc, it should be in C:\Users\MyUser.jenkins but it is not there.
Moreover, there is no *%JENKINS_HOME%* and I cannot find even a single file/directory named Jenkins in the file system.

Looking at the official documentation:

[image: Official documentation]

I'm sure I'm missing something very easy, but still, I cannot understand what is going on.

I ran the containers with the following command:

> docker run -p 8080:8080 jenkinsci/blueocean

And I configure the system (successfully) going to

> http://localhost:8080/configure

I hope you can help me undertanding this a little bit better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your jenkins home directory will be within the container. Use `docker exec -it <container-id> bash` or `docker attach <container-id>` to connect to the container. Once within the container browse to `/var/jenkins_home/` which is the jenkins home directory

Comment: I'm confused. I mean, I did it and the command gave me no feedback. Moreover, where can I find /var/jenkins_home/? Is it gonna be on the file system somewhere?

Comment: Cab you post what command you tried and the response you see ?

Comment: As I said I tried the command you gave me: 'docker attach <container-id>' 
I see no response, literally nothing.
Btw, per documentation of Jenkins I should see the logs in the folder %JENKINS_HOME%, but nothing there

Comment: Did you replace <container_id> with the actual container id of your container ?

Comment: ok that I'm new to this topic, but yes, I replaced the placeholder you put with the actual id of the container :)

Comment: Anyway as mentioned in my answer above the jenkins home dir will be within the container. From your post it appears you are looking on the host system (Win 10) which is not where Jenkins is installed

Comment: Ok, so here is where I am lost. Yes I'm looking in the host system, but this is what I'm told in the documentation. I'm running the container from w10 and so I guess it is installed on w10

Comment: No. Jenkins is installed within the container NOT on your host Win 10 system. The docker command you ran will spin a new container with the jenkins docker image. Hope this helps

Comment: It sure helps! At this point, how can I see the "file system" where JENKINS is running?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184969/discussion-between-ben5556-and-ff8mania).